# Delphi: What is type of window appears after you click a ComboBox

Tags: delphi

There is a window appear after you click that triangle icon of ComboBox. This I know it's not just a panel like object because for example in the following picture it' out of main form.

What is its type and how can I create something like this?

[image]

Answer (score 8):

It is a standard ListBox control that the ComboBox creates internally (its HWND is accessible via the [CB_GETCOMBOBOXINFO](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775839.aspx) message). It is implemented as a free-floating window (so it can appear outside the ComboBox's parent window), except when the `Style` property is set to `csSimple`, in which case the ListBox resides as a child within the ComboBox's client area instead.

Comment: The free-floating window is a form? How can I create something like that?

Comment: It's not a form. It's not a Delphi control. It's a Win32 listbox.

Comment: In the Win32 api, just about any windowed control can be free-floating with the right flags applied not just forms. But in VCL, only forms are floating.

Comment: It is not exactly a standard listbox. It should at least have been modified a bit for it's actually a [`ComboLBox`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633574(v=vs.85).aspx#system).

Comment: My guess is that Microsoft simply derived `ComboLBox` from `ListBox` to add the extra ComboBox logic to it.  But it is still more-or-less a standard ListBox in general.  You can send standard ListBox messages directly to the list's HWND.